# Tense in Resume writing - A small question

Tags: resume

I am writing my resume and have got one confusion regarding the tense to use when detailing present and previous job descriptions. I will ask my question with an example so that it is easy to understand what I am trying to ask.

I want to write "Understand and discuss requirements" as a bullet in the descriptions of both my present and past jobs.

Do I write it as:
1. "Understand and discuss requirements"
                   *OR*
2. "Understand**ing** and discuss**ing** requirements"
                   *OR*
3. "Underst**ood** and discus**sed** requirements"

Which of the above should go for the present job and which one for the past? 
I believe it would be the 3rd one for past jobs, but some confirmation would be good.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, as a hiring manager, "understanding requirements" on a CV is kind of like "breathing air": meaningless fluff that anybody can claim.  Go into specifics if you can, eg. "led requirement specification negotiations on massive project X with demanding client Y".

Comment: Thank you. Good point, but I don't have enough experience and not at the level where I could use your suggestion. I am more technically oriented, and haven't led or done such negotiations. I am not at a senior position right now, so my responsibilities are limited to understanding and discussion requirements.

Comment: For sure I would not use "understanding and discussion requirements".  So you were not at the level.  Go into the specifics.  Understand / understanding / understood requirements is meaningless fluff.

Comment: I always use past tense for everything on my resume. In the 20 years I've worked as a professional, I've gotten plenty of replies and offers. I want to say I found this tip in a book as I graduated college (the professors didn't cover this in the senior classes),

Comment: Thank you for the good advice, Frisbee and Tim. I will think about it and see if I can improve what I have written.

Comment: Looks similar. Thanks for pointing it out. I will give a detailed look at the answers in that post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When to use what tense:

**Past Tense**

> Achievements:
>
> - Led the team which is responsible for _______________
> - Designed a system which _____________

**Present Tense**

> Project/internship/job details and/or responsibilities:
>
> - Design and deploy the model which predicts the number of goblins in Hogwarts kitchen.
> - Understand and execute exploratory analysis on the patterns of unicorn movements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But won't responsibilities come under present tense?

Comment: @LoveEnigma  If for current job, **yes**

Comment: Okay. Before the tasks/responsibilities bullets in my resume, I have written  for present job: "Key responsibilities include:", and for past  "Key responsibilities included:" And then I have just listed the bullets under both jobs in present tense, like "Discuss requirements", "Support software team", "Prepare design documents", and so on. Does it look right to you?

Comment: You write **Key responsibilities include** for past job also.  Only the bullets have past tense

Comment: Ok, but any reason why I cannot write what I mentioned above? Since bullets are job details/responsibilities, they can be present tense for any job, right? For achievements in past and present jobs, past tense would be right, as you have mentioned.

Comment: @LoveEnigma Sorry about that, you can write it as *included* :)   My bad!

Comment: No problem at all. :) Thanks. Finally, bullets can just be in present tense (1st option in my original post) for both past and present jobs?

Comment: bullet points for responsibilities <-- Yes.  For achievements <-- No

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: :) Wish I could mark two answers. Sorry Kilisi, but you were equally helpful. Both your's and Dawny33's  answers helped me to infer this question.

Comment: @LoveEnigma You can upvote them as a thank you gesture :)

Comment: Yeah, I did, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputations for them to show up. This was my first post at workplace.stackexchange.com. :)

Answer (score 0):

Past tense if it's a description of what you did. Present tense if it's a description of the job requirements. I would say.

eg,. I understood and discussed requirements...

I was required to understand and discuss requirements...

Part of my role was/is understanding and discussing requirements...

It really depends on the context of the bullet list.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. What I am trying to write is a list of tasks/activities that were a part of my job responsibilities/requirements. Since it is a bullet list, I just want to highlight some regular & important activities. So based on your answer and what I am trying to write, I think present tense would be the right choice for both past and present jobs. One differentiating thing I have written in my resume before the bullets for present job is: "Key responsibilities include:",  and for past as "Key responsibilities included:" (added 'd' for past tense). Am I correct?

Comment: yes, that looks right with the 'd' so for 'key responsibilities include/d', would be 'understanding and discussing requirements' I would think.

Comment: Ummm, I am confused again. Sorry. Actually, my gut feeling told me that I should write "Understanding and discussing requirements" and that's what I had written earlier. But after looking at a few profiles on LinkedIn and some resume examples where present tense was used, I thought to confirm this. By the way, does it really matter in this particular case whether I use the 1st or 2nd option? Does it really make sense to think a lot about it? After all it is not grammatically wrong to write either of them for resume purpose, isn't it?

Comment: I would go with your gut, the other is not correct in context, not to me anyway. Whether it would make a difference if I was reading your resume, frankly it wouldn't unless you were applying for a job like translating or something, but I would definitely notice it.

Comment: Yes, these are subtle things which some may notice and some may not. Thanks for your time and thoughts. It definitely helped.